# Javascript disable space key for change password textboxes

Tags: javascript, keyboard, passwords

,Hi all,

```
var veri = {
YeniSifreTextBox: $('#YeniSifreTextBox_I').val(),

YeniSifreTekrarTextBox: $('#YeniSifreTekrarTextBox_I').val(),
};

if (veri.YeniSifreTextBox == '' || veri.YeniSifreTekrarTextBox == '') {
alert("Password Can not be empty!");
}
else if (veri.YeniSifreTextBox != veri.YeniSifreTekrarTextBox) {
alert("Passwords dont not match !");
}
```

I can control password can not be empty and passwords dont not match with above codes.

I want to disable to enter space key while user write password.

User must never use space in keyboard inside of 2 textboxes.

1.textbox YeniSifreTextBox_I

2.textbox YeniSifreTekrarTextBox_I

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the below javaScript code to block the space key,

```
function RestrictSpace() {
    if (event.keyCode == 32) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea onkeypress="return RestrictSpace()"></textarea>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: when i press space it won't allow. But this code is not working when i copy and paste spaces.

Answer (score 2):

```
                        <input type="number" 
                           id="cardNumber"
                           name="cardNumber"
                           required
                           onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode === 32)
                           return false;">
```

You can implement the same functionality, without creating a custom function.