# How to make JavaScript block the 'space key' inside a textbox

Tags: javascript, passwords, onkeypress

First of all, I've already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780304/javascript-disable-space-key-for-change-password-textboxes) and it doesn't work for me, unless I put the script in the HTML page (I didn't do it because I've a page for all the scripts). Another solution that does work but that I haven't understand is this:

```
<input type="password" id="pwd" required pattern=".{8,16}" title="8 characters minimun, 16 characters maximum" name="fpwd" placeholder="Password" size = "13" onkeypress="return (event.keyCode != 32&&event.which!=32)>
```

So, the question is: why the first solution works only if the script is in the HTML page?

Comment: You may want to check for the keyCode on the event handler of this input. Since you mentioned you are having a js, there might be a handler I suppose

Comment: second solution returns true or false based on if the space bar is pressed

Comment: Please post the 'this solution' that doesn't work (with citation as appropriate), that way your question is self-contained. As you don't understand what the code in your (currently posted only) example is doing, look up those events at MDN.

Comment: @WinterSoldier Ops, I don't think I've a handler for it on the JS file :s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `onkeypress` event handler is executed every time the user enters a character into the text field.

The entered character's key code is stored in the event's `keyCode` or `which` parameter depending on the environment (browser).

If the character code equals the key code for SPACE (`32`), the event handler returns false, which causes the browser to dismiss the event, i.e. prevents it from adding the typed character to the input field.

Type in this snippet to see the different key codes:

```html
<input onkeypress="return console.log(event.keyCode || event.which), (event.keyCode != 32 && event.which != 32)" />
```

Comment: Oh, I got it! That's why I have to double check that value isn't 32 for both keyCode and which. I tried to search something on the Internet but that 'which' word confused me a lot. I'm checking other answers, if I understand how to make the first solution works on JS file I'll do that, otherwise I'll use this and mark this answer as accepted. For now, thanks!

Comment: @MC23 Check out the [MDN page on the `KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent) for more info!

Comment: Uh, didn't find it when I searched for this, thank you. I've completely understand now :)

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
document.getElementById("pwd").addEventListener('keydown', function (event)
{
    // if the keyCode is 32 ( space key was pressed )
    if (event.keyCode === 32) {
        // prevent default behaviour
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

#### Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a7yprnjd/

Comment: It works but it's too complicated for me, thanks anyway
PS: epic name/profile pic combo btw ^^

Comment: Also, you should read this: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/unobtrusive-javascript-important